# Which Desktop environments do not require 3D acceleration?

Tags: video, desktop-environment, 3d

I have two situations in which I need to run desktops without any 3D acceleration.

1) I often run Ubuntu and CentOS VMs on a machine who graphic card does not play nicely with VirtualBox's 3D acceleration (bug in the drivers).

2) Accessing remote sessions

This isn't a quick "log in and check something", I could be working at them for hours, and the performance hit from using LLVMpipe really annoys me, so I could really use a Desktop Environment that runs on Modern distros but doesn't require 3D acceleration, but I can't find reliable info easily.

So:

Which currently maintained, mature, DEs don't require 3D acceleration (note, I'm not asking for an opinion on whether they are any good, I just want a list).

Comment: Which ones do require 3D acceleration, apart from Unity?

Comment: Out of the box Gnome 3 and Cinnamon definitely do (could be that cinnamon can be configured not to). I think plasma does as well? - i.e. all the major ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what kind of features you want from a desktop or what you generally expect from it:

- **MATE**: fork of Gnome 2, traditional environment with lots of features
- **i3**: tiling window manager and easy to configure
- XFCE
- **dwm**: there are many tiling window managers based on or similar to dwm (catwm, monsterwm, ocelot, ..)
- xmonad
- awesome
- herbstluftwm
- OpenBox
- **icewm**: preinstalled on openSUSE/SLES as fallback WM
- LXDE

Comment: I'm makring this as the answer given that it has the most exhaustive list. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm using **XUbuntu** which comes with **XFCE** by default. This I believe doesn't need 3D acceleration.

See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62502/are-there-3d-effects-on-xubuntu-hardware-accelerated-graphics) related post on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

practically any small VM without compositing.

New on scene is for example LXQt, which are trying create fully capable lightweight desktop.

[LXQt Lightweight Desktop Manager](http://lxqt.org/)